# get Jsonarray as response by android volley by sending some data

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-volley

Can someone tell me....how to get jsonarray as reponse by android volley library...I used the method called **jsonArrayRequest** but there is one thing....I want to get jsonArray response by sending some data to the php script.....My php script contain three variables ...and i will pass these three variables from android app....then my php script genertae the jsonarray response based on these three values....I used getParams method to send the data to the php script...but when i demand jsonArray response the android never hit the getParams method.....but when i use stringRequest......it will work properly......But i want jsonArray response not the stringRequest....

Can someone help me how to do this??
Thanks in advance

```
    package com.example.shreeram.dreamapp;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class QuestionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        // declare all views...
        TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5;
        Spinner spinner;


        //php script url.....
        String server_url = "http://192.168.212.2/question.php";


        ArrayList<String> question;
        ArrayList<String> option1;
        ArrayList<String> option2;
        ArrayList<String> option3;
        ArrayList<String> option4;
        ArrayList<Integer> correct;
        ArrayList<Integer> q_id;
        ArrayList<Integer> id;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);


            //receive data from previous activity....data is .....value of click and listclick..
            Intent in = getIntent();
            Bundle b = in.getExtras();
          final Integer click =  b.getInt("click");
           final Integer listclick =  b.getInt("listclick");


            //initilize all views...
            tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_question);
            tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewop1);
            tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewop2);
            tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewop3);
            tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewop4);
            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);


            //Initialize all array list....here data will come from mysql database or jsonarray...
            question = new ArrayList<String>();
            option1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            option2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            option3 = new ArrayList<String>();
            option4 = new ArrayList<String>();
            correct = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            q_id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            id = new ArrayList<Integer>();


           //Set the different fonts....
            final Typeface myfont1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Vollkorn-

    Regular.ttf");
            final Typeface myfont2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/PT_Serif-

    Web-Regular.ttf");






            //This is the request from server....for jsonarray.....

            //This is starting of jsonArrayrequest.......
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest

    (Request.Method.POST, server_url,null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                            //response will come here....

                            int i = 0;
                            int j = response.length();

                            //retrieve all json object from json array...and fill that data to the 

    corresponding arraylist...

                            while (i<j)
                            {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    id.add(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                                    q_id.add(jsonObject.getInt("q_id"));
                                    question.add(jsonObject.getString("question"));
                                    option1.add(jsonObject.getString("op_1"));
                                    option2.add(jsonObject.getString("op_2"));
                                    option3.add(jsonObject.getString("op_3"));
                                    option4.add(jsonObject.getString("op_4"));
                                    correct.add(jsonObject.getInt("correct"));


                                    i++;




                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }

                            //set fonts to all the views....

                            tv1.setTypeface(myfont1);
                            tv2.setTypeface(myfont1);
                            tv3.setTypeface(myfont1);
                            tv4.setTypeface(myfont1);
                            tv5.setTypeface(myfont1);


                            //set values to the views from arraylist....

                            tv1.setText(question.get(0));
                            tv2.setText(option1.get(0));
                            tv3.setText(option2.get(0));
                            tv4.setText(option3.get(0));
                            tv5.setText(option4.get(0));




                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                    //Error will appear here.....
                    tv1.setText("error happened...");

                }
            }){

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                    Map<String , String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    //put values in the params....
                    params.put("category",""+click);
                    params.put("quizno",""+listclick);

                    //return params....and values to the php script...
                    return params;
                }
            };

            //This is end of jsonArrayrequest.....


            //Create a new request queue.....
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


            //Add jsonarray request to the request queue....
       requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);





            //End of oncreate method....
        }




        //End of activity class......
    }   


and this is the php script..... 


<?php

//get values from android app......

$click = $_POST['category'];
$listclick = $_POST['quizno'];


//This is fix....
$language = 1;







$user = "root";
$password = "";
$host = "localhost";


//All database names....

$db_name1 = "history_english";
$db_name2= "history_hindi";
$db_name3= "world_english";
$db_name4= "world_hindi";
$db_name5= "science_english";
$db_name6= "science_hindi";
$db_name7= "sports_english";
$db_name8= "sports_hindi";
$db_name9= "india_english";
$db_name10= "india_hindi";
$db_name11= "computer_english";
$db_name12= "computer_hindi";
$db_name13= "politics_english";
$db_name14= "politics_hindi";
$db_name15= "business_english";
$db_name16= "business_hindi";



//Conditions for fetch jsonarray.....

if($click==1)
{

    //means history database....

    if($language==1)
    {
        //means english database...history_english
        $con1 = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db_name1);




        //Make sql query......
        $q1 = "select * from t_".$listclick;

        $result1 = mysqli_query($con1,$q1);
        $response = array( );
        $num1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);


        //Encode data as jsonarray.....

        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
        {

            array_push($response,array("id"=>$row1["id"],"q_id"=>$row1["q_id"],"question"=>$row1["question"],"op_1"=>$row1["op_1"],
            "op_2"=>$row1["op_2"],"op_3"=>$row1["op_3"],"op_4"=>$row1["op_4"],"correct"=>$row1["correct"]));
        }


        echo json_encode($response);





    }
    else
    {
        //means hindi database.....history_hindi

        $con2 = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db_name2);


        //Write code later.....

    }










?>
```

Comment: If `stringRequest` works just transform the string to a `JSONArray` when you receive it using the `stringRequest`

Comment: But my php script return jsonArray.. ........can i convert jsonarray into string.. .using php code.. .....then please tell me. ....how to do that.. ...thanks for your answer. ..

Comment: Look at my answer below. You will not need to change your PHP code (if it does indeed return a JSON encoded `JSONArray` String).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information you provided you have no problems using the Volley `StringRequest` method--the download functions properly and the `getParams()` method is called correctly.
Know that the server request will return a string! If you are using `json_encode()` in your PHP code then that string will be a JSON encoded `String`. You did not provide the PHP code...so I will just have to assume that everything PHP side is set-up properly.

You can use that JSON encoded string to create a `JSONArray` simply using `JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);` where "response"  is the returned value from `StringRequest`.
So just create a method like the `downLoadDataVolley()` method below and pass the url as needed.

```
private void downLoadDataVolley(String url){
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        //INFO:: The response is of String type, but it is a JSON encoded String..
        // !! as long as the PHP code is indeed returning JSON!!
        // IF the JSON encoded string is structured as a JSONArray then do this...

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
            Iterator<String> it = o.keys();
            while(it.hasNext()){
                String key = it.next();
                String value = o.optString(key, "NA");
                Log.e("Try to Parse", "key = " + key + " value = " + value);
            }
            //String s = o.optString("key", "NA");
        }
    }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }){
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String , String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        //put values in the params....
        params.put("category",""+click);
        params.put("quizno",""+listclick);

        //return params....and values to the php script...
        return params;
    }};
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

In your case you can call `downLoadDataVolley(server_url)` and everything should work fine(as it did for you previously) except this time you transform the string into an `JSONArray`.

Instead of just `String s = o.optString("key", "NA");` you will need to add your code instead, but I highly recommend using `optString()` or `optInt()` since these methods give you the ability to use optional fallback values.

**Please let me know if you have any further questions.**

---

**DISCLAIMER**

I type this in a standard text editor... so I did not have the advantage of AutoCorrect for my code--There may be a typo or two.

Comment: I have try your method.......when i use StringRequest.......But now i am unable to retrieve a single object from jsonArray.......My jsonArray contain 10 jsonObjects......and each jsonObject contain 8 key value pair.......Now i want to fetch first key value pair of first jsonObject.......when i try this......instead of printing first data...it will print the whole array....Please tell me.....how to retrieve data from this......

Comment: My JSON parser was just an example.. you need to put your own key names in the for loop.

Comment: I have try with my own key value pair.......but it will print the complete array...not the single value.....the for loop is used to get the object from jsonarray and then string from json object......i have try it....but instead of printing single data ...it print the whole jsonArray....

Comment: Please edit your post and give an example of the JSON your receive. Otherwise I will not be able to help

Comment: I have add the php script at the end of android java code.......with comment line........//this is php script...

Comment: please visit this link i have put my jsonArray response here..........http://programmingengineer.blogspot.com/2018/10/json-array-response-of-my-php-script.html

Comment: @Ankit :: Take a look at my edited code.. I have added an `Iterator` that should iterate through the keys of the individual JSONObjects in the JSONArray. Try that and see what you get in the LogCat

Comment: @Ankit :: Take a look at my edited code.. I have added an `Iterator` that should iterate through the keys of the individual `JSONObjects` in the `JSONArray`. Try that and see what you get in the LogCat. Also, please note that according to the JSON you posted to the website, that neither "id" nor "correct"  are of type `int`. Notice the quotation marks `"id":"1"` and `"correct":"2"` this shows the content is of type `String`.

Comment: When i use iterator. ...and when i write......... Iterator it = array. keys()......   It is showing me the red line on keys.. .........Is there any simple solution. ...by which i can get the jsonArrayResponse.. ....by sending some data to the server.. ..... In case of stringRequest.. ......it is little bit complex. .....

Comment: @Ankit :: Sorry--that should be `Iterator<String> it = o.keys();` "o" for the newly create `JSONObject`. Try that instead.

Comment: Thank u very much.. .. Now it work fine., ...now finally i am able to get all the values differently.. .......thank u once again.. ....

Comment: @Ankit :: I'm glad it worked for you.  If you feel like my answer has helped, please consider accepting the answer as "correct". Thank you